# Google App Engine SSL Version 2.7.11 Library Un/Supported

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, ssl, tls1.2

According the the documentation...

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

SSL Version 2.7.11 supports TLS v1.0, v1.1, and v1.2 (where I need TLSv1.2 for APNs communication).

And

Google App Engine / Python supports SSL Version 2.7.11 (as of July 2016)

When I add this to my app.yaml ...

```
libraries:
  - name: ssl
    version: 2.7.11
```

...and attempt to deploy the application (via appcfig.py on the commandline or "deploy" on the launcher) I receive an error...

```
Error parsing ./app.yaml: ssl version "2.7.11" is not supported, use one of: "2.7"
```

If I specify version 2.7 or "latest", I get SSL version 2.7 without TLS v1.1 or v1.2 support. If I omit SSL from the "libraries" clause in yaml, the ssl module is not supported in the application on import.

How should I proceed to "import ssl" with TLSv1.2 support?
Or have I overlooked an app.yaml configuration option?

the pertinent portion of my app.yaml follows...

```
api_version: '1'
runtime: python27
threadsafe: false

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 4
  max_pending_latency: 250ms

builtins:
- remote_api: 'on'
- deferred: 'on'

libraries:
- name: django
  version: '1.2'
- name: ssl
  version: '2.7.11'

inbound_services:
- warmup
```

Comment: maybe file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?

Comment: I believe SSL version 2.7 does provide TLSv1.2 support.

Comment: @GAEfan With the "version: '2.7'" specified in the app.yaml, a logging.debug(dir(ssl)) within the deployed application confirms only thee protocols PROTOCOL_SSLv23, PROTOCOL_SSLv3, and PROTOCOL_TLSv1.

Comment: Make sure you update to the latest version of the SDK:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/download  That should get rid of the 2.7.11 error

Comment: May also want `gcloud components install app-engine-python-extras`.  Not sure if ssl 2.7.11 is in there.

Comment: run `logging.debug(ssl.__doc__)` to see the constants available.

Comment: I tested with 2.7.11 in my app just fine with both appcfg and gcloud app deploy. I'm guessing you have an old SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you update to the latest version of the SDK:

cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/download

That should get rid of the 2.7.11 error.  Older (pre 2.7.11) versions had that error.

Comment: This is exactly the issue. Was GoogleAppEngineLauncher v1.9.36 (1.9.36.544). Downloaded and installed v1.9.50 (1.9.50.2) this morning and ssl v2.7.11 deployed without error. Further, logging.debug(ssl.__doc__) and logging.debug(dir(ssl)) reveal the additional SSL protocols, PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1 and PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2.